# vba define range ending text

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm trying to process a data file and export each section to a separate text file. I can specify a range to export without issue (A1:A58) but I never know how many lines I'll need so it should be dynamic.  For example, sheet1 will export 58 rows because row 1 will always start the range (A1) and 58 (A58) contains the text "Referring" indicating the end of that record. Then, those rows will be deleted.  The next record will start with specific text "NewRecord" (A1) and complete with the words "Referring" again.

```
Sub ExportRange()
Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim output As String
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim i As Long
Dim MyOldFile As String
Dim MyNewFile As String
MyFolder = "C:\Users\profile\Documents\test"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\text.txt")
i = i + 1
MyOldFile = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
MyNewFile = MyFolder & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B20") & "_" & i & ".txt"
For Each r In Range("A1:A37").Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        output = output & "," & c.Value
        Next c
    output = output & vbNewLine
Next r
Open "C:\Users\profile\Documents\test\Text.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
Name MyOldFile As MyNewFile
MyFile = Dir
Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at Do Until, something like `do until r.value="Referring"` on `range(a1:a10000).end(xlUp)`  then `r.row` will be your delete to point

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste those lines in.  There is a loop.  I didn't copy that part.  I need help in identifying the range in the line 
For Each r In Range("A1:A37").Rows
Maybe I should re-consider my approach.  to include stopping at "Referring" instead of trying to name the range.

Comment: `Range("A1:A37").Rows` will return range "A1:A37" so that iterating through its single cells `Cells` will still return those cells: are you actually interested in pasting only column "A" values?

Comment: So you are looking for the cell that contains "Referring" and in your example it is A37?  You want to be able to do that dynamically?

Comment: My example shows how it works now; but that's not the goal.  I want to replace it with a reference to the most appropriate range.  i.e. whatever cell contains "referring."  Yes, all data is in column A because it is a data import from a text document.  I'm trying to use excel to parse the data out into individual files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the first row that contains "Referring" searching from the top down and create a range from it that is used in the For loop.

```
Sub ExportRange()
Dim c As Range, r As Range, LoopRange as Range
Dim output As String
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim i As Long
Dim MyOldFile As String
Dim MyNewFile As String
Set LoopRange = Range("A1", Cells(Range("A:A").Find(what:="Referring", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlNext).Row, "A"))
MyFolder = "C:\Users\profile\Documents\test"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\text.txt")
i = i + 1
MyOldFile = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
MyNewFile = MyFolder & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B20") & "_" & i & ".txt"
For Each r In LoopRange.Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        output = output & "," & c.Value
        Next c
    output = output & vbNewLine
Next r
Open "C:\Users\profile\Documents\test\Text.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
Name MyOldFile As MyNewFile
MyFile = Dir
Close
End Sub
```

Comment: This works when the file is consistent.  Thank you!  I'll keep working to see if I can prep the text file to standardize it more consistently.